# Need help creating an Object in a class, and assigning values to the Member Functions

Tags: c++

Assignment details (my code is placed below):

Give a C++ class declaration called SavingsAccount with the following information:

Operations (Member Functions):

1. Open account (with an initial deposit). This is called to put initial values in dollars and cents.
2. Make a deposit. A function that will add value to dollars and cents
3. Make a withdrawal. A function that will subtract values from dollars and cents.
4. Show current balance. A function that will print dollars and cents.

Data (Member Data):

1. dollars
2. cents

Give the implementation code for all the member functions.

Write code that will create an object called bank1. The code will then initially place $200.50 in the account. The code will deposit $40.50 and then withdraw $100.98. It will print out the final value of dollars and cents. 
The following output should be produced: 
Dollars = 140 cents = 2.

NOTE: You must perform normalization on cents. This means that if cents is 100 or more, it must increment dollars by the appropriate amount. 
Example: if cents is 234, then dollars must be increased by 2 and cents reduced to 34.

PART 2: Change the program to allow the user to input the initial values, deposit
and withdrawal.

I have the code figured out for PART 2, because I've done programs involving functions and user input before. But I can't figure out how to re-do the functions for PART 1 to place pre-assigned numbers in the Dollars and Cents variables, and make the other functions still work correctly to get the correct balance at the end

Here's my code:

```
// PART 2: Allow the USER to input Initial, Deposit, and Withdrawl values.
// NOTE: You must perform normalization on cents. This means that if cents is
// 100 or more, it must increment dollars by the appropriate amount. Example: 
// if cents is 234, then dollars must be increased by 2 and cents reduced to 34.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// SavingsAccount class declaration:
class SavingsAccount 
{
    private:
        int dollars;
        int cents;

    public:
        void setOpen(int, int);
        void setDeposit(int, int);
        void setWithdrawl(int, int);
        void showBalance();

};

//*******************************************************
// setOpen function, allows user to open a new Account **
//*******************************************************
void SavingsAccount::setOpen(int d, int c)
{
    dollars = d;
    cents = c;
    cout << "Input Dollars for Opening Balance:" endl;
    cin >> "$" >> dollars;
    cout << "Input Cents for Opening Balance:" endl;
    cin >> "." >> cents;
    // Normalize dollars and cents
    while(cents >=100)
    {
        cents-=100;
        dollars++
    };
};

//************************************************************
//setDeposit function, adds a Deposit to the user's Account **
//************************************************************
void SavingsAccount::setDeposit(int d, int c) 
{
    dollars = d;
    cents = c;
    cout << "Input Dollars to Deposit:" endl;
    cin >> "$" >> dollars
    cout << "Input Cents to Deposit:" endl;
    cin >> "." >> cents
    dollars += d;
    cents += c;
    // normalize dollars and cents
    while(cents >= 100) 
    {
        cents -= 100;
        dollars++;
    };
};

//*******************************************************************
// setWithdrawl function, withdrawls money from the user's Account **
//*******************************************************************
void SavingsAccount::setWithdrawl(int d, int c)
// normalize dollars and cents
{
    dollars = d;
    cents = c;
    cout << "Input Dollars to Withdrawl:" endl;
    cin >> "$" >> dollars;
    cout << "Input Cents to Withdrawl:" endl;
    cin >> "." >> cents;
    while(c >=100) 
    {
        c -= 100;
        d++;
    };
     if(c > cents) 
    {
        dollars--;
        cents += 100;
    };
    dollars -= d;
    cents -= c;
};

//******************************************************************
// showBalance function, shows the user's current account balance **
//******************************************************************
void SavingsAccount::showBalance()
{
    cout << "Your current balance is: $" << dollars << "." << cents << endl;
};
//******************
// Function Main  **
//******************

int main()
{
    char answer;    // To hold Y or N input.

    cout << "This program will help you open and manage a new Savings Account!" endl;
    SavingsAccount::setOpen(int d, int c);

    cout << "Do you wish to make a Deposit?" endl;
    cout << "Press 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." endl;
    cin << answer;
    do 
    {
        SavingsAccount::setDeposit(int d, int c);
    } while (answer = 'Y' || answer = 'y';

    cout << "Do you wish to make a Withdrawl?" endl;
    cout << "Press 'Y' for Yes, and 'N' for No." endl;
    cin << answer;
    do 
    {
        SavingsAccount::setWithdrawl(int d, int c);
    } while (answer = 'Y' || answer = 'y';

    SavingsAccount::showBalance();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to <s>DumpMyHomework</s>StackOverflow! Please read the FAQ, post your code and effort here in a a minimal, complete example and say where you have problems specifically. Above all, **always tag homework as such** so it can be told apart from other questions and treated accordingly (e.g. hints rather than solutions, assume newcomer, etc.)

Comment: Printing formatted output requires the `<<` operator for every token: `cout << "text" << endl`. This is used for example in many classic "hello world" programs for C++.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't figure out how to re-do the functions for PART 1 to place pre-assigned numbers in the Dollars and Cents variables...

Sounds like something that should happen automatically when you create an instance of `SavingsAccount`. Take a look at how to create class constructors and default value arguments.